# Simple predicate of <get hold of>

Tags: predicate

A Simple Predicate is simply the verb or verb phrase in a sentence. Since some verbs, for example phrasal verbs, have additional words other than the "stem word" would they be considered part of the simple predicate? 
For example, which is *generally* the simple predicate of "Get hold of"

1. *Get*
2. *Get hold*
3. *Get hold of*
4. if none of the above, please specify the answer.

If you need a specific example for context, then you may identify the simple predicate of:

> I *need to get hold of* Tom's address

And it would be appreciated if you could justify and cite any references I could refer to?

Answer (score 1):

*Hold*, meaning a grasp on something, is a very old word in the language. The *OED* traces it to 1300, and it is idiomatic with a number of verbs, including *catch*, ***get***, *lay*, *lose*, *seize*, and *take*. We may therefore analyze *I got hold of Tom's address* as

> *I* (Subject)
>   ***got*** (Verb)
>   *hold* (DirectObject)
>   *of Tom's address* (Prepositional Phrase Complement of *hold*)

(I've changed your example to show that the simple predicate is *got*, eliminating the distraction of *need*+to-infinitive.)

There are two reasons not to consider *got hold* as a phrasal verb. First, it's understandable from its parts. *To get hold* is to obtain a grasp. This is quite different from the verb in

> I have to **look after** my brother

which doesn't mean that I have to look past him. Secondly, we can add *adjuncts* freely between the two words:

> I **got** *a definite though tenuous* **hold** on the handle.

We can't generally do this with a phrasal verb:

> ***** I have to **look** *this afternoon* **after** my brother.

The *indefinite article* may appear, as in the song lyric

> You've really **got** *a* **hold** on me

so it might be tempting to think that the phrase started with *get ahold*, with *ahold* the (now obsolete) nautical adverb for bringing a ship into the wind to hold her steady. But the *OED* finds an earlier use for *get hold* than for *ahold* (the latter fittingly from *The Tempest*).